# Write a recursive function in C that prints all odd numbers(backwards) and when it reaches 1 it stops

Tags: c

I am first time poster here. Like the tittle says I need to print all odd numbers via a recursive function. The problem is that I have created a simple program that does that, but when it reaches 1(which should be the point where the program stops) the program crashes and I honestly do not see where is the problem. My professor said that I forgot to put a return somewhere, but I honestly do not know where. So if someones can point out the problem that would be great(ps. I am using Code::Blocks as my IDE).

```
int main() {
  int a, b;
  printf("Unesi neki broj:    \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  b = koko(a);
  printf(b);
}

int koko(int a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    return a;
  }
  if (a % 2 != 0) {
    printf("Ovaj broj je neparan:  %d  \n", a);
  }
  koko(a - 1);
}
```

Comment: Read you compiler warnings. They will tell you what's wrong. Hint: last line in main function.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` too. They will inform you what's wrong with the recursion.

Comment: what should `koko` return, for eample for the value `a = 15`? Should it always return 1?

Comment: Also since you are new to SO you might want to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to declare the function `koko`; for using it in `main` function.

```
int koko(int a);
```

Secondly, `printf(b)` need to define the type to print out:

```
printf("%d\n", b);
```

Finally, Using `return koko(a - 1);` instead of `koko(a-1)` because this function has to return an `int` value.

Then, the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int koko(int a);

int main() {
  int a, b;
  printf("Unesi neki broj:    \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  b = koko(a);
  printf("%d\n", b);
  return 0;
}

int koko(int a) {
  if (a == 1) {
    return a;
  }
  if (a % 2 != 0) {
    printf("Ovaj broj je neparan:  %d  \n", a);
  }
  return koko(a - 1);
}
```

Comment: if it is useful for you, accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0xe8.png)

```
int koko(int a) 
{
    if (a % 2 != 0) 
    {
        printf("Ovaj broj je neparan:  %d  \n", a);
    }

    if (a == 1) {
        return a;
    }

    koko(a - 1);
}

int main() 
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Unesi neki broj:    \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    b = koko(a);

    printf(" koko(a) return %d", b);

    return 0;
}
```